# Button click event not fired in Fragment

Tags: android

I have a problem when I insert this code in the fragment

```
public class CameraConnectionFragment extends Fragment{

  boolean clicked = false;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_connection_fragment, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

        clicked = true;

      }
    });

    return view;

    }

}
```

The problem is essentialy that the variable clicked doesn't change when I press the button when the application is running. I've put an if statement which evaluate the clicked variable but it's always set to false even if I keep pressing the button.

The code where the button is located (camera_connection_fragment) is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<org.tensorflow.demo.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<org.tensorflow.demo.RecognitionScoreView
    android:id="@+id/results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<org.tensorflow.demo.OverlayView
    android:id="@+id/debug_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="getMe"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `clicked` value must be change when button is clicked. i hope you are using boolean value in same class

Comment: yes, it's a boolean type and is in the same class where I use the if statement, which is in an override method.  What I would like to do is to trigger the if event when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you put the if statement that checks the clicked variable? Maybe, your code already passes the if statement before your click listener is triggered. Look at the following code:

```
boolean clicked = false;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_connection_fragment, container, false);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //Put your logic in the if(clicked) control.
    clicked = true // you can delete this line
    (your logic)
  }
});

return view;

}

@Override
   protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //You can delete the below if check and move your logic to onClick method
    if(clicked) {
     (your logic)
    }
}
```

In the above code, `clicked` variable check in `onStart` always false, since it is already executed before your click listener is triggered. If it is possible you can check clicked variable in click listener's `onClick` method. If you share the place where you put your if logic we can provide more proper answer.

Comment: ok I got it, so the variable is always false. It's exactly as you wrote the code so, how could I have the variable always false but when I press the button it become true and trigger the if event?

Comment: As I said if it is possible you can put your if logic in onClick method. I have edited my answer you can check it. Actually, you do not need even if(clicked) check, you can delete if you wish you can directly put the code block into onClick method.